# Flutter | How can I enable geolocation in an iframe

Tags: flutter, iframe, geolocation

I've implemented an iframe to open a link within a web environment since Flutter web doesn't support FlutterWebView. However, I'm encountering an issue where the iframe requires geolocation permission. I've already provided the 'allow="geolocation *"' attribute, but it's not functioning as expected

this is my code

```
HtmlWidget(
            '<iframe allow="geolocation *" src="${url}"></iframe>',
          ),
```